# How did Sonny buy the hotel?

Tags: plot-explanation, second-best-exotic-marigold-hotel

In The Second Best Marigold hotel after the hotel inspector resigns Sonny offers to drive them...

> him

To the

> Viceroy Hotel.

Very soon after this Sonny announces that he has bought it with help from his investor.

But the hotel inspector made it perfectly clear that because of their resignation the letter of appraisal would mean nothing... how did Sonny raise the money to buy it?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how human beings work. Because it was a human being, not a computer, making the final decision, the fact that he no longer worked for the company did not mean that it was completely isolated from his opinions. It's not that his appraisal would mean nothing, it's that he wouldn't be submitting a formal report. It's very possible that he included his opinion upon his resignation, and he may also have notified Evergreen that their competition was also eyeing a collaboration in Jaipur. So when Guy and Sonny went to the Viceroy, they could easily have contacted Burley, who probably flew out to see the place and close the deal. Since the Viceroy was in dire financial straits, and Sonny's company caters to the same clientèle who were frequenting it, it would not have been very difficult for a company like Evergreen to convince them to sell. Not to mention the Viceroy owners probably had a strong recommendation from Madge, Norman, and Carol. Given the way these things tend to work and the corporate philosophy of Evergreen, it's perhaps even possible that The Best Exotic Marigold franchise will continue to operate the Viceroy Club's existing functions with reduced membership fees as a trade-off for the loss of exclusivity in using the facility.

Answer (score -3):

Evergreen did the deal with Sonny with the help of Guy who fell in love with Sonny's mother.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.